# How to use cv2.VideoCapture(0) on bullseye in raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, bullseye

**I am using Cam module v3 legacy camera stack does work with v3 cannot use raspistill or vid apps dont work. Enabling legacy stack will not work**